# TFS Aggregator can buse used with custom process template?

Tags: tfs, tfs-aggregator

Hi I would like to know if TFS Aggregator can be used only with default process templates (Scrum, Agile, CMMI) or it can be used with custom process templates too. If yes, what kind of configuration I have to do in order to use it with my custom process template?

I customized backlog portfolio LEVELs, workitem types WIT and STATES using italian language.
`Iniziativa` means Feature, `Requisito Utente` means User Story, `Bozza` means Draft and so on.

```
- Iniziativa LEVEL
     Iniziativa WIT (STATES: Bozza, Proposto, Aperto, Chiuso)

- Requisito Utente LEVEL
     Requisito Utente WIT (STATES: Bozza, Proposto, Approvato, Soddisfatto, Rifiutato)
```

and so on ...

For instance, I would like that when a TFS user changes the state of `Iniziativa` workitem from `Aperto` to `Chiuso`, then all `Requisito Utente` workitem childs that are in `Approvato` state automatically change to `Soddisfatto` state.

Furthermore, I need a bottom up check: I mean that a workitem child cannot go in final state if its workitem father is not yet in final state. For instance, if a TFS user tries to change a `Requisito Utente` workitem state to `Soddisfatto` when its `Iniziativa` workitem father is not yet in `Chiuso` state, then the state change of work item child must be blocked in some way (it is possibile to show a popup with an error message?).

Thanks

Comment: Could you specify what have you customized for your process template?

Comment: What error did you get when you use it with your custom process template?

Comment: I didn't get any error. I didn't understand how configure TFS Aggregator in order to use it with my custom process template (described above).

Comment: What have you tried? Have you achieved what you want in a default process template? You may start here: https://tfsaggregator.github.io/using/, and refer to the samples in C:\Program Files\TFS Aggregator after you install the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes. Just remove the policies below in the file `TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.policies`:

```
<templateScope name="xxx" /> 
<projectScope projects="xxx" />
```

Comment: Ok, but what about the use of custom workitem types with custom states?

Comment: I've tried calculated field aggregation in a custom process template, and it worked. It's supposed to depend on rules and policy you apply in TFSAggregator2.ServerPlugin.policies, but not what you customized.

Answer (score 0):

Since you write the policy, you have total control over which actions must be done when. The Aggregator will happily work with custom fields, custom states even whole custom workitem types. Since each rule specifies the work item types, fields etc, just use the Italian naming, or rely on the ReferenceNames.

As for the State/Reason field, we actually query the TFS instance for the work item workflow rules and use that to follow the default state transitions if all you want to do is "move it along".

The blocking of edits is not something the TFS aggregator can do, since TFS only notifies after the changes have already been saved. You will need to use the standard work item rules in TFS WIT XML to do what you can do there. Or you'd need to implement a rule that reverts the changes to their previous state by takin the values from the last correct revision and saving the work item again. **Note**: this will not block the change for the user, but will "rollback" change on the server. This may be awkward to your users.